# How to resolve __vi_internal_vim_alias: command not found?

Tags: linux, fedora, sudo, vim

I have recently upgraded to Fedora 33 (Linux 5.9.16-200) on my machine. I am running vim-enhanced version 8.2. When I type `sudo vim` (or even `sudo vi`) in order to edit files with admin privilege, I get the following error.

```
sudo: __vi_internal_vim_alias: command not found
```

I am not sure what is causing this. Vim loads fine without the sudo. Could you please tell me how to troubleshoot this? Thank you.

---

**Update:**
Upon executing `which vim`, I get the following result.

```
alias vim='__vi_internal_vim_alias'
    __vi_internal_vim_alias ()
    { 
        ( test -f /usr/bin/vim && exec /usr/bin/vim "$@";
        test -f /usr/bin/vi && exec /usr/bin/vi "$@" )
    }
```

I am not sure what did this and where. Maybe it's a Fedora 33 thing. Given the above information, what do you suggest is a permanent fix?

Comment: I'm wondering if you get the same error executing `sudo vim --clean`.  Is there a `/root/.vimrc` or `/root/.vim/vimrc` or `/root/.exrc`?

Comment: Yes, same error for that. No, those files do not exist.

Comment: How about `sudo \vim`?

Comment: Your user `vim` must be, or try to execute, a script, a link, an alias, or even an executable that is not in root's `PATH`.  There are probably some other failure modes too.  I wish I could find the POSIX standard to reference all the details, but a POSIX shell (not just `bash`) must not do alias expansion if the commandline begins with a backslash.  Please refer to the actual standard/documentation for the details (I don't know them.), I usually just try the `\command` trick when things seem wacky (usually encountered when asked to use another user's "customized" shell).

Comment: What do you get for `env -i HOME="$HOME" bash --login --norc -c 'which vim'`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs `/usr/bin/vim`

Comment: I would look for the alias in `~/.bashrc` and any other initialization files it sources or executes.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have checked `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.bash_profile`. They do not have these modifications.

Comment: I think I found it, although I'm still on Fedora 32.  On my system, this alias and function definition appear in `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh`.  Now the question is why your system uses this alias for the user but not for root.  Is there perhaps a `/etc/profile.rpmnew` or any other `.rpmnew` files that are perhaps, at least partially, better suited to your upgraded version of Fedora?

Comment: Strange, isn't it? No, the only ones there are `/etc/chrony.conf.rpmnew` and  `/etc/nsswitch.conf.rpmnew`, which are not relevant I suppose?

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now.  Perhaps searching/asking at https://ask.fedoraproject.org/ might provide a better explanation/solution.  At least you know the `\command` trick now.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm puzzled about this one... Since `sudo` is not really expected to expand aliases on the commands it runs... Did you figure out why that is happening?

Comment: @filbranden Not yet.

Comment: I'm still on Fedora 32... I'll see if I upgrade to F33 to take a closer look at why they might have done to the Vim packages there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @scy mentioned unalias-ing the vi and vim is a workaround solution for keeping the sudo="sudo " alias so it can be used with other aliases.

Expanding his/her answer for the different shells:

**ZSH Shell:** Add to the **.zshrc** file (of the user you want to be affected by the changes)

- located at:

For Fedora 33 Workstation(or Server or another non-atomic OS Distro):
**/home/$USER/.zshrc**

For Fedora CoreOS 33.x (or Silverblue 33 or other similar atomic OS Distro):
**/var/home/$USER/.zshrc**

- the following lines of code:

```
[ "$(type -w vi)" = 'vi: alias' ] && unalias vi
[ "$(type -w vim)" = 'vim: alias' ] && unalias vim
```

**BASH Shell:** Add to the **.bashrc** file (of the user you want to be affected by the changes)

- located at the same locations, respective to the OS/Distro specific location for the $USER 's home directory (check the directions for Fedora Workstation, etc...)
- the following code:

```
[ "$(type -t vi)" = 'alias' ] && unalias vi
[ "$(type -t vim)" = 'alias' ] && unalias vim
```

**P.S.** Concerning **ZSH Shell**, this solution can resolve similar problems with other CLI applications that are in a similar initialization situation. For example: **mc** (Midnight Commander). Meanwhile, **mc** will not have any such problem in **BASH Shell**.

Comment: It also affects Fedora 32. And this solution works. Thank you and thanks to @scy

Answer (score 5):

Hitting the same issue on Fedora 33.
This seems due to having an alias defined for `sudo` in my environment:

```
$ alias sudo
alias sudo='\sudo '
```

Due to this, somehow bash resolves aliases passed as arguments to `sudo` alias, as shown in the example below:

```
$ alias foo='echo foo'
$ sudo foo
foo
```

I would have expected to have this instead:

```
$ sudo foo
$ sudo: foo: command not found
```

Deleting this alias worked for me. This alias was created by `/usr/local/bin/alias.sh`, part of `synth-shell` project (https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell)

Comment: Really useful first post, thanks! ;) I’ve experienced the issue as well and indeed removing the `sudo` alias fixes it. However, if you’d like to _keep_ that `sudo='\sudo '` alias (since it allows you to use aliases from your `.bashrc` together with sudo), you could remove Fedora’s `vi`/`vim` aliases instead. I’ve added `[ "$(type -t vi)" = 'alias' ] && unalias vi` and `[ "$(type -t vim)" = 'alias' ] && unalias vim` to my `.bashrc` as a workaround for this issue.

Comment: When I do `alias sudo`, I get `alias sudo='sudo '`. Also, I don't have the `/usr/local/bin/alias.sh` file.

Comment: As stated in the answer and my comment, you can either remove that `sudo` alias (it’s probably somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) or remove the `vi` and `vim` aliases.