# Configure zsh jobs output and fg behavior

Tags: zsh, job-control

Until recently I was pretty satisfied with how the `fg` and `jobs` command worked in my zsh, i.e.:

- just `fg` -> foreground the most recently backgrounded job again
- `jobs` -> display command name (incl. args) and perhaps even PID (don't recall)

After the latest Fedora 33 updates these zsh behaviors changed in a (for me) pretty annoying way:

- `fg` now foregrounds the job with the lowest job id (i.e. not the most recently backgrounded job)
- 'jobs' output is much less verbose, e.g.:

```
[3]  + suspended (signal)  mutt
[4]  - suspended
```

where job `4` is a vim session ...

So I presume that some zsh defaults changed. Thus my question: How do I configure the more useful behaviors for `fg` and `jobs` back?

(That means how do I get `jobs` to always display command names with arguments and pid and `fg` to foreground the most recently backgrounded job?)

(I'm currently at zsh-5.8-3.fc33.x86_64.)

**Edit 1:** A sample session:

```
$ zsh
~ $ man man

zsh: suspended  man man
~ $ vim blah
zsh: suspended  
~ $ jobs
[1]  - suspended  man man
[2]  + suspended  
~ $ fg
[2]  - continued  

zsh: suspended  
zsh: suspended  
~ $ jobs
[1]  + suspended  man man
[2]  - suspended
```

Note that I suspended the foreground jobs via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> each time. Look for the `+` marker in the `jobs` output. What also surprises me is that I get 2 `zsh: suspended` lines after suspending vim for the second time. Looks like the suspend signal is delivered to the already suspended man process, again?

**Edit 2:** The job-control issue only appears if one job is `vim`. Thus, some details on how vim is invoked:

```
$ which vim
vim=__vi_internal_vim_alias
$ alias vim
vim=__vi_internal_vim_alias
$ typeset -f __vi_internal_vim_alias
__vi_internal_vim_alias () {
    (
        test -f /usr/bin/vim && exec /usr/bin/vim "$@"
        test -f /usr/bin/vi && exec /usr/bin/vi "$@"
    )
}
```

Ok, these definitions don't come from my profile. It appears they come from a system change. If I invoke `vim` as `\vim` the job control issues don't appear anymore. Looks like the sub-shell messes with zsh's command line string creation and other things. See also [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627998/1131) related [reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/l84wph/fedora_33_vivim_vi_internal_vim_alias_can_someone/).

So where does this come from:

```
$ cd /etc
$ grep -r __vi_internal_vim_alias . -r 2>/dev/null
./profile.d/vim.sh:__vi_internal_vim_alias()
./profile.d/vim.sh:        alias vi=__vi_internal_vim_alias
./profile.d/vim.sh:        alias vim=__vi_internal_vim_alias
./profile.d/vi.sh:__vi_internal_vim_alias()
./profile.d/vi.sh:        alias vi=__vi_internal_vim_alias
./profile.d/vi.sh:        alias vim=__vi_internal_vim_alias
$ rpm -qf ./profile.d/vim.sh 
vim-enhanced-8.2.2146-2.fc33.x86_64
$ rpm -qf ./profile.d/vi.sh 
vim-minimal-8.2.2146-2.fc33.x86_64
```

Comment: Zsh very rarely changes defaults. Are you sure that both are recent changes? I've sometimes observed that zsh seems to “forget” the command line of a job, but it hasn't happened to me often enough to track it down.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, I am. Of course, it could also be caused by a change in the kernel or a library. Although I can't reproduce it with bash. Regarding reproducibility, the weird new behavior is stable - cf. my question update for a sample session.

Comment: For information I can't reproduce this with zsh 5.8 on Ubuntu. Does it matter which programs are involved? (I wonder if it could be this version/configuration of vim doing something “weird” that confuses zsh.)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' ok, it really only happens with vim! Where `vim` is really a weird system-wide alias! See my latest update for details. That means with `\vim` job-control works as before ...

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' the latest Fedora vim update now installs small wrapper shell scripts under `/usr/bin/vim` and `/usr/bin/vi` which test for `/usr/libexec/vim` and fallback to `/usr/libexec/vi`. I really don't understand the motivation behind all this effort trying to alias and wrap to always make `vim` work. I mean what's the big deal if `vim` fails when you don't have it installed? Do you have an idea what could be behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by Fedora started defining system-wide `vim` aliases that start vim in a sub-shell.

Since this seems to break stuff left and right those aliases are now being rolled back: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1918575